# Android Listview Adapter not Updating/Refreshing UI when i removed my only One record item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Why my list view is not updating its User Interface when im removing Only one item from my adapter it retains its current item display but the record is already removed from my list adapter..?

My Delete item is working when more than one record retains from my adapter but when i removed all items i retains the last item i removed from the UI.

Here are the code i tried to refresh my UI but still not working... im Using SimpleAdapter

```
case PaymentModeCollection.CHECK:
    //deletePaymentMode(arrListSet , paymentIdentity);
    deletePaymentMode(arrCheck , paymentIdentity);
    //checkEditOrAdd = true;
    //arrCheck.remove(0);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //listView.refreshDrawableState();
    //listView.invalidate();
    //onPause();
    //onResume();
break;





public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, items, resource, from, to);
        }


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  int colorPos = position % colors.length;
  //if(!(view == null)){
  view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
  //}
  return view;
}
```

> Here is my deletePaymentMode

```
    protected  static void deletePaymentMode(ArrayList<?> containerSetPaymentMode,String reference){//Set<ArrayList<?>> containerSetPaymentMode
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i <= containerSetPaymentMode.size() -1; i++){
        if(containerSetPaymentMode.get(i) instanceof Cash){


        }
        if (containerSetPaymentMode.get(i) instanceof Check) {
            Check tempCheck = (Check) containerSetPaymentMode.get(i);
            if(tempCheck.getxCheckNo().contentEquals(reference)){
                Log.d(TAG, "ITEM TO BE DELETE FOUND");
                arrCheck.remove(i);
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
    */



    Iterator<?> ia = containerSetPaymentMode.iterator();



    while (ia.hasNext()) {
        Object paymentObject = ia.next();


        if (paymentObject instanceof Cash) {
            ArrayList<Cash> tempArr = (ArrayList<Cash>) paymentObject;


        } else if (paymentObject instanceof Check) {
            Check tempCheck = (Check) paymentObject;
            if(tempCheck.getxCheckNo().contentEquals(reference)){
                ia.remove();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: can you show `deletePaymentMode()` method code?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your deletePaymentMode() does but you should always make changes (add, delete, update) on your list which holds your items for your ListView:

```
myListViewItems.remove(itemToRemove);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should be enough to remove the item.

Comment: i already managed to removed my item.. but when i removed the last item its not refreshing my listview to no items to be show..

Comment: Did you check if the item is really deleted from your list? Maybe you have an error in your logic for deleting the last item.

Comment: i already checked that.. the UI is not updating.. its weird.. and the onclick event is also triggering but my item is already deleted and gives me null pointer..

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException? This is a kind of important point which you did not mention yet.

Comment: when i switch to my another fragment and goes back to my listview fragment the listview is refreshed..

Comment: it become null because the item is already deleted... the Listview UI is not updating...

Comment: Why is the item already deleted? When do you delete the item?

Comment: on list item click i have a menu for edit and delete.. when i clicked delete (it will remove the item clicked) and my UI is not updating.. after that i tried to clicked that item i recently deleted if it exist... then its a null pointer because i successfully deleted the item.

Comment: Ah okay. Hmm thats really strange.

Comment: my brain is about to explode... i cant figure it out -____- :(

Comment: Unfortunately I can currently not test this. In the evening I will try it at home.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, my listview wasn't updating well after an item deletion in the Adapter. This was solved by adding the following line in the layout:

**android:**

```
 listSelector = "@ android: color / transparent"
```

and removing the attribute 
`"android: background"` from this.